# C++ cwchar error

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am trying to compile the regex_search function on the vxWorks gcc platform. I was testing with an example to see if I can use it without any issues. The example file includes the following three headers.

```
#include <string> 
#include <map> 
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
```

The errors I get are as follows

```
include/c++/3.4.4/cwchar:73: error:   `::mbstate_t' has not been declared
include/c++/3.4.4/cwchar:114: error: `::btowc' has not been declared
.........
.........(similar "not defined" errors)


c++/3.4.4/cwctype:20: error: `::wctrans_t' has not been declared
c++/3.4.4/cwctype:20: error: `::wctype_t' has not been declared
.........
.........(similar "not defined" errors)
```

I want to know what cwchar and cwtype headers do. When I open them and see, they contain lot of preprocessor #ifdefs which seems to be checking for compiler specific information.

My supervisor asks me to turn them off. How can I do it?

Comment: Hello! I had the same problem using the Xcode IDE (Mac). I found out that it was because I put the directory `/usr/local/include` in the header search paths, to be **recursively** search. That was bad, and disabling the **recursive** search solved my problem. So I think your compiler is picking up some wrong header files with duplicate names (perhaps for backward compatibility). I don't know if that helps, I know it's 8 years late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your supervisor wants you to turn off the cw-support you can try to define BOOST_NO_CWCHAR and BOOST_NO_CWCTYPE in your project settings.

see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html